# Terraform azurerm_key_vault access_policy overides existing access policies

Tags: azure, terraform

I have following code to create azure key vault:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  name                = "example"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  sku_name            = "standard"
  tenant_id           = var.tenant_id
  
  access_policy {
    tenant_id = var.tenant_id
    object_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity.principal_id
    secret_permissions = [
      "get",
    ]
  }
  
}
```

Assume following scenario:

- deploy infrastructure using terraform
- change key vault access policies manually
- redeploy using terraform

Terraform will remove access policies that were created manually.
Is there a way to tell terraform to not remove existing access policies?

Comment: Are you aware of [`ignore_changes`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes)? You might want to question why you don't want Terraform to manage that key vault policy though and instead commit to making your changes via Terraform instead or at least backporting the changes to your Terraform code so that Terraform doesn't want to change anything.